# How to autocomplete python class in vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vimrc

In sublime text 3, if I'm editing a `file.py` and I type `class` it will automatically create this for me

```
class ClassName(object):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```

If I'm editing a C++ file, obiously it's not the same. How to do that in vim? I already have `jedi-vim` it's awesome but doesn't do that.

Comment: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.